# How do I supply default script for 'npm run'?

Tags: node.js, npm

My question doesn't really lend itself to a single line subject. If someone types a script name that's not in my package.json, I want to override printing 'missing script' and instead print a text file that lists the commands in my `scripts` node and what they do.

Is there a way to do this?